# Get Request Returns 404 on Product Flask backend ,React Frontend (render.com)

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, get, render.com

I have a simple  app it works on my local machine .
Here is the sample react code API_URI is my backend domain that render gave me:

```
  const fetchProducts = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      let response;

      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the Content-Type header
      };

      if (searchQuery) {
        response = await axios.get(`${API_URI}/api/aggregated/matched/getall?page=${currentPage}&sort=${selectedSortOption}&query=${searchQuery}`, { headers });
      } else {
        response = await axios.get(`${API_URI}/api/aggregated/cheapest/getall?page=${currentPage}&sort=${selectedSortOption}`, { headers });
      }
```

Here is the controlle

```
 @all_cheapest_computers_blueprint.route('/cheapest/getall', methods=['GET'])
def get_cheapest_options():
```

i registered that in my app.py

```
app.register_blueprint(all_cheapest_computers_blueprint,url_prefix='/api/aggregated')
```

here is the backend logs:

```
Aug 20 05:25:20 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2023:02:25:20 +0000] "GET /api/aggregated/cheapest/getall?page=1&sort=ascendive_price HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "mybackenddomain/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

This used to work in my local environment ,when i deployed it to render in network tab the data looks like it fetched and downloaded but it still returns->Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
(additional info the API_URI is the backend server domain that is given by render) i hardcoded the return value of my backend api like this->return jsonify("fsdgfchgfdsfghcfxdzs<asdzfghcfxzc<xcvb") and it still gives the same error,i am stuck its the first time im trying to deploy i used the documentation but could not solve it )any help appreciated